# Why my php double foreach + if condition don't give expected result?

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

I'm trying to proceed datas that I get with PDO & fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC).
Now when my function should return 2 results, only 1 is actually returned.

$tracksinpl is like a collection of array with a 'TrackId' column :

in my example I use :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [TrackId] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [TrackId] => 5
        )

)
```

$tracks is like a collection of array with an 'id' column

in  my example I use :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => abc
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => test
    )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [title] => this is title
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [title] => title1
    )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [title] => title2
    )

)
```

now the code that I use to proceed datas

```
$count=0

foreach($tracksinpl as $trinpl)
{
    foreach($tracks as $track)
    {
        if($track['id'] == $trinpl['TrackId'])
        {
            $count= $count +1;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when count is returned, its value is 1 and should be 2, why ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: your same code works here - https://3v4l.org/Hb7jX. Is this your actual `foreach()` code? or just an example? Could you post a `print_r()` or `var_dump()` of your `$tracksinpl`/`$tracks`.

Comment: edited my post with print_r of arrays. This is my actual code yeah.

Comment: you have `$tracksinpl` in both `$tracksinpl is like a collection of array with a 'TrackId' column :` and `$tracksinpl is like a collection of array with an 'id' column`. I assume the 2nd line should be `$tracks`, correct?

Comment: Yea sure my bad, i try to compare datas from both arrays and count

Comment: Well in your updated sample of `$tracksinpl` and `$tracks`, the count should only be `1` as there is only a match of `5`. `$tracksinpl` is `[4,5]` and `$tracks` is `[1,2,3,5,6,7]`, so not sure why you think it should be `2`. https://3v4l.org/dDpvk

Comment: Okay, thank you for pointing out my stupidity, all id present in $trackinpl should be present in $tracks but it's not the case. Again thank you